# url rewrite removing index page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write an .htaccess file that will

a) when navigating to mysite.com/myusername (which is non existent) it will show the contents of mysite.com/dmp/temp/myusername

b) hide .php from the URL's

When going to mysite.com it however it shows me the contents of mysite.com/dmp/temp folder. If I add /index in front then it will work.

Everything is working as intended except that. How can I make sure users that simply navigate to mysite.com are served index.php (without actually writing /index/ or /index.php) and also not redirected to the /dmp/temp folder?

**Code:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) !^temp
RewriteRule ^(.*) dmp/temp/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at your two regular expressions:

```
^([^\.]+)$
```

and

```
^(.*)
```

**First one:** Match every query which do not contain . with length 1 or more.
**Second:** Match everything from length 0 or more.

So if you open `http://mysite.com/` you have an empty query, and it's matched by the second regex. This means it tries to open `dmp/temp/`.

Try changing the second regex from `^(.*)` to `^(.+)`. That means it will match only if you have a query of length 1 or more, and it will not match `http://mysite.com/`. Hopefully, you then will go to standard behaviour, showing the index.* file according to server settings (in your case index.php)